# Android - Проблема с ListView

Tags: android, listview, java

Есть ListView, заполняемый ~200 значениями. По нажатию на кнопку список должен очиститься и эти значения должны измениться на новые. Сейчас я использую `listview.invalidateViews();`, он работает отлично, если находиться в начале списка. Если же его прокручивать/быть не в начале, то при нажатии на кнопку приложение крашится из-за `invalidateViews`. Как ещё можно обновить ListView, чтобы не выкидывало?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: добавлю от себя - если размер списка (кол-во элементов) изменилось (особенно в сторону уменьшения), а метод notifyDataSetChanged позвать забыли, то может (скорее всего) быть падение программы. (уточнение - падение будет, если кол-во элементов уменьшилось, а список прокрутили в конец).